# Need help calculate 90th percentile

Tags: teradata

```
SELECT
     session_start_dt
    ,PERCENTILE_CONT(0.9) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY excess_wait)
        OVER (PARTITION BY session_start_dt)
FROM Excess_Wait_AB
```

This query results is following error:

> [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 15.10.00.22] [Error 3707] [SQLState
>   42000] Syntax error, expected something like a name or a Unicode
>   delimited identifier between ')' and the 'OVER' keyword

.

Comment: Please format the source by prepending 4 spaces before each line.

Comment: Teradata only supports the aggregate version of `PERCENTILE_CONT`, see https://downloads.teradata.com/blog/dnoeth/2011/06/missing-functions-percentile-disc-percentile-cont-median

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT
     session_start_dt
    , PERCENTILE_CONT(0.9) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY excess_wait) as pcntl
FROM Excess_Wait_AB
```

This is another option:

```
SELECT
     session_start_dt
    , PERCENTILE_DISC(0.9) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY excess_wait) as pcntl
FROM Excess_Wait_AB
```

Difference between them explained [here](https://info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_16_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035-1145-160K/are1472241112659.html).